# Timezone is wrong when picking city (Copenhagen)

Tags: performance, core, timezones

The timezone-setting (in 'Settings' >> 'Generel' >> 'Timezone'), seems to be ignored. I've set it to be 'Copenhagen' (value: `Europe/Copenhagen`).

But the servers time is still 1 hour ahead of the actual time in Denmark.

---

### Debugging

If I simply add these lines in the top of my functions.php-file:

```
$datetime = new DateTime();
$datetime_str = $datetime->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
error_log( $datetime_str );
```

Reload a random page and go to my error-log, then I get this result:

```
[24-Mar-2021 16:12:08 UTC] 2021-03-24 16:12:09
```

'UTC'?! Hmm...

But if if add replace above-written three lines with this:

```
date_default_timezone_set ( 'Europe/Copenhagen' );
$datetime = new DateTime();
$datetime_str = $datetime->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
error_log( $datetime_str );
```

Then it outputs this:

```
[24-Mar-2021 17:12:13 Europe/Copenhagen] 2021-03-24 17:12:13
```

'Europe/Copenhagen' -> Yep. And the time is correct as well.

And if I try to set it to some other value (like 'UTC+8'), then it still says: `[24-Mar-2021 16:12:08 UTC] 2021-03-24 ...` in the debug-log.

---

### Considerations

It could be somewhere in my theme or in a plugin. But it seems excessive to start to deactivate all plugins and set another theme, just to debug this minor thing.

So my question is:

1. Is it a big performance-hit, to leave my fixing line in the top of the functions-file:
   `date_default_timezone_set ( 'Europe/Copenhagen' );`
2. Can anyone figure out, why the timezone is set to UTC instead of what the value I've set in the WordPress-settings-page?

Comment: Why would it be anything other than UTC? `$datetime->format` is straight PHP - it is not specific to WP, or aware of WP settings. You have to tell it what time zone to use.

Comment: See this answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30946/default-timezone-hardcoded-as-utc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 2. ... why the timezone is set to UTC instead of what the value I've set in the WordPress-settings-page

WordPress calculates offsets from UTC, therefore [WordPress sets the default time zone to UTC](https://build.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.7/wp-settings.php#L66) and not the specific time zone you selected in the Settings → General admin page.

> 1. Is it a big performance-hit, to leave my fixing line in the top of the functions-file: `date_default_timezone_set ( 'Europe/Copenhagen' );`

Maybe it's not a big one, but even so, you should *not* change the default time zone.

Because if you do, then the following (critical issue) will be reported by the Site Health tool (`wp-admin` → Tools → Site Health):

> PHP default timezone was changed after WordPress loading by a `date_default_timezone_set()` function call. This interferes with correct calculations of dates and times.

However, in certain cases, you may use `date_default_timezone_set()`, but you should restore the default time zone back to UTC once you've done with your code:

```php
date_default_timezone_set ( 'Europe/Copenhagen' );
$datetime = new DateTime();
$datetime_str = $datetime->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
date_default_timezone_set( 'UTC' ); // restore it to UTC
```

But then, WordPress provides its own date/time functions which apply the time zone set via the admin settings page, e.g. [`wp_date()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_date/) (or in the past, [`date_i18n()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/date_i18n/)), so you could simply utilize those functions. E.g.

```php
// Display current time in MySQL format using wp_date():
$datetime_str = wp_date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );

// Or you could just use current_time():
$datetime_str = current_time( 'mysql' );
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't get why it's important that I change it back to UTC? Then the timestamp in my error-log will be in UTC and not in the timezone for the site. What is the advantage of that? ... But you're right that it appears in Site Health, if I leave the changed timezone in functions.php.